# how to delete azure sql server and leave only serverless database copy

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an sql server (srv1) with an sql database (db1).
I want to go serverless.

I made a copy of db1 --> db2, and provisioned it to be serverless.

db2 is showing under srv1. Why? I asked it to be serverless.

I want to delete this srv1 without erasing db2.

how can i do this?

Comment: you should consider using Azure Database Migration Service. more details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql?toc=/azure/azure-sql/toc.json

Comment: also, if the new database is showing under original server, then, the something definitely wasnt done right.

Comment: Please kindly ignore Jay's comment. This is totally incorrect information.

Comment: ah. apologies folks. I mostly use web apps so my knowledge is limited. that is why, when in doubt, i post a comment rather than a answer. i stand corrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview) is a compute tier for single databases in Azure SQL Database that automatically scales compute based on workload demand and bills for the amount of compute used per second. The serverless compute tier also automatically pauses databases during inactive periods when only storage is billed and automatically resumes databases when activity returns.

**It's a price tier and not really 'serverless'. And no matter which kind of Azure SQL database, all still need the Azure SQL Server to host it.**

You made a copy of db1 in the same Azure SQL Server(I don't know how you created it), the new copy 'db2' will in the same server in usually. Unless you create a  .bacpac file of DB1 and import to other Azure SQL Server.

When you delete the Azure SQL Server, all the database will be deleted and we can not restore it.

You could scale the database to serverless price tier on Portal easily:

SQL Database-->Configure-->General Purpose-->Serverless:
[image]

HTH.